# Chrome Extension: Inject different CSS files depending on Option in localStorage

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So, I'm trying to make an extension that has an options page to select a variation of CSS which is then implemented.

I can use a content script to add CSS to a page successfully, with my manifest being:

```
{
  "name": "Extension",
  "description": "Description.",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "options_page": "options.html",


    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["http://www.google.com*"],
        "css": ["Test.css"]
      }
    ]
}
```

Which works fine, the Options page is just the default example HTML and JavaScript from the [Options Page on Google](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options.html).

That works with a value being stored to localStorage, what I'm unsure of is how to use that stored value to add different CSS based on that value. Like having the stored value of "red" will load one CSS file to a website, while "green" will load a completely different one instead.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the `content_scripts` attribute from the manifest (since there is no way to "customize" it dynamicaly) and use **[Programmatic Injection](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi)** instead (and more specifically **[chrome.tabs.insertCSS](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-insertCSS)**).
(Note: Depending on how you use/invoke it you will need to declare the `activeTab` or `tabs` permission in your manifest, as well as the appropriate **[host match pattern(s)](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html)**.)

Example:

**In `WhatEverView.html`'s JS context**:

```
var color = ...;
localStorage.setItem("color", color);
```

**In `background.js`:**

```
function injectCSS(tabId) {
    var color = localStorage.getItem("color");
    var path = (color == "green") ? "file4green.css" : "file4red.css"; 
    chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tabId, {
        file: path,
        allFrames: false
    });
}

/* Call `injectCSS` in a callback of an event, e.g.
 *  - When the bowser-/page-action is clicked
 *  - When a tab is updated etc */
```

Comment: Awesome. Sorry, I only gave two options in the initial question, but say I had 20 different options should I just use a switch or heaps of if else statements to set path?

Comment: You could use `switch` or `if...else` (there are equivalent). You could also have the saved item be the name of the file (e.g. `color: "green"` refers to a file named `green.css` etc), so then the code will be much less cluttered: `var color = localStorage.getItem("color"); var path = color ? color + ".css" : "default.css";`

Comment: I marked it as accepted since it did solve my question on applying different CSS files. Thanks mate. Can't upvote though, not enough reputation.