# Chrome Extension applying to more URLs than it should be

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So, I'm trying to make an extension that would only apply itself to say www.google.com/bbb and sub pages of it like www.google.com/bbb/ccc but not www.google.com/aaa.

My Manifest has this for permissions:

```
  "permissions": ["tabs", "http://www.google.com/bbb*"],
```

But it's still applying to any page under www.google.com, not just www.google.com/bbb as I want it to.

All of this is running in background.js.

Comment: Try `"http://www.google.com/bbb/*"`

Comment: @megawac, no dice. Still applies itself everywhere.

Comment: What does "apply" mean in this context ? What exactly is your extension doing ?

Comment: @expertSystem It's applying a custom CSS, which you helped with last night. I have all that working fine, I just need to constrain which URLs it will apply the CSS to.

Comment: @Vectera: If you are injecting programmatically, why don't you do the filtering yourself ?

Comment: @Vectera: Did you try my proposed solution below ? Did it work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear from **[the docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html)**, but (being it bug or a feature) the host match patterns that can be declared in manifest's `permissions` attribute, does not care about the path:

```
"[scheme]:[host]/*"
```

It will only apply to the `scheme` and `host` and will ignore the `path` part.

---

Since **[you seem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19973538/chrome-extension-inject-different-css-files-depending-on-option-in-localstorage)** to be injecting prgrammatically, you can do the filtering based on the path manually:

```
/* In `manifest.json` */
...
"permissions": [
    "tabs", 
    "http://www.google.com/"
],
...

/* In `background.js` */
// ...some event was captured, involving tab <tabX>...
...
var urlRegex = /^http:\/\/www.google.com/bbb/;
if (urlRegex.test(tabX.url)) {
    injectCSS(tabX.id);
}   // ...else do not inject CSS
...
```

<sub>***Note**: This could work equally well without the "http://www.google.com/" permission, but including it is more efficient, as it reduces the number of URLs your background page will have to check (and reject). I.e. it will only have to check URLs starting with "http://www.google.com/"*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but this helped me after a long hunt... (╭ರ_•́)

You could add your files in [`"content_scripts"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) of the manifest file, and use its `"matches"` property, the same way you write your `"permissions"` URLs. Then [refine your content script matches](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#match-patterns-globs) using its `"exclude_matches"`, `"exclude_globs"` and `"include_globs"` properties (where "globs" are pieces of the URL you want to include or exclude). So:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://www.google.com/bbb/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "src/inject/your_scripts.js"
      ],
      "css": [
        "src/inject/your_styles.css"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
```

Keep in mind to achieve your example you'll need the `"run_at": "document_end"` so files are injected immediately after the DOM is complete, but before subresources like images and frames have loaded (as per links above). Hope this helps someone!